# Access watson retrieve and rank behind a proxy in Node

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

I need to know if the R&R service can be used behind a proxy. 
Take a look at the next part to see my investigations.
The code I'm using was working at my home. (No firewall/No Proxy, only a router)

---

I started from the following code. 
https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/personality-insights-nodejs-web-starter

I try to execute it locally and it was working using the following configuration to be able to install the modules.

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
npm config set proxy http://x.x.x.x:xx
npm config set https-proxy http://x.x.x.x:xx
npm config set strict-ssl false
set http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:xx
set https_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:xx
set HTTP_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x:xx
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://x.x.x.x:xx
```

As it was working I started playing around with R&R. But I'm only having an error.

```
Error searching for documents: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 158.85.132.88:443
```

Where the ip address corresponds gateway.watsonplatform.net

```
ping gateway.watsonplatform.net
PING gateway.watsonplatform.net (158.85.132.88) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

**Because of the firewall the ping are blocked**

During my investigations I found that when executing my test for the R&R service every time two ICMP request are send.

[image: packet listening]

Probably because of the firewall. But why this service would need to send ICMP packets ?

Just to recap:

1. The code is working when there is no firewall/no proxy
2. The personnality Insight service is working behind proxy/firewall
3. The R&R isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ### EDIT
>
> After some investigations I've found that there was a bug in the Solr-client so it is currently impossible to make it work.
>   More info [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/issues/421) on this github issue.